# How to run a few API calls in a loop and then use callback function

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, callback, twilio-functions

I'm trying to write a function but can't seem to figure out how to run a loop of API calls on an array of strings, and only after all the API calls are completed to call the callback function. No matter what I try either the function fails or the callback function is called too soon.

Here is my code:

```js
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  const sidArr = [];
  const cc = event.ccSid;
  const exp = event.expSid;
  const cvc = event.cvcSid;

  sidArr.push(cc, exp, cvc);

  const resArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sidArr.length; i++) {
    client
      .messages(sidArr[i])
      .update({ body: '' })
      .then((message) => {
        if (resArray.length == sidArr.length) {
          callback(null, resArray);
        } else {
          resArray.push(message.sid);
        }
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method returns a `Promise`. Loop over the `sidArr` array and call the `messages` and  `update` method for each item in the array. Store the returned `Promise` in a new array.

You can wait for all promises in an array to finish with the static `Promise.all` function. The result will be an array of all resolved promises.

Then loop over each result once more to extract the `sid` property.

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  const sidArr = [];
  const cc = event.ccSid;
  const exp = event.expSid;
  const cvc = event.cvcSid;

  sidArr.push(cc, exp, cvc);

  const requests = sidArr.map(message =>
    client
      .messages(message)
      .update({ body: "" })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  );

  Promise.all(requests)
    .then(messages => messages.map(({ sid }) => sid))
    .then(sids => callback(sids))
};
```

Comment: I ran your code and got the following syntax error `"message": "Unexpected token '}'"` I think I can't use `async` and `await` in Twilio runtime functions as it shows a warning in the code editor. Maybe that's why I'm getting the error. can you change it to without it?

Comment: I've updated the answer without async / await. Also I forgot to call the `callback` function.

Comment: I tried your updated answer and got this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection: undefined` (I fixed the syntax error)

Comment: That might mean that one of the `client.messages(message).update({ body: "" })` requests doesn't update successfully. The error indicates that the promise that is retured by the `update` method is unhandled. We can handle it by adding a `catch()` method after the `update` method. This `catch` method will run whenever an error occurs in the `update` method. Otherwise it will be skipped. Adding the `catch` block might give you more insight over the nature of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `async` and `await`, then you can just use `Promise.all()` and run them in parallel like this:

**Run them in parallel:**

```js
let promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sidArr.length; i++) {
  promises.push(
    client
      .messages(sidArr[i])
      .update({ body: '' })
      .then((message) => message.sid)
  );
}
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((results) => callback(null, results))
  .catch((err) => callback(err));
```

Of course, it's a bit of an anti-pattern to be turning a promise into a plain callback like this.  You really ought to just change the interface and return the promise back to the caller so the caller can just use `.then()` and `.catch()` on the promise directly.

**Run them sequentially without `async` and `await`:**

Or, if you want to run them sequentially (not in parallel) without using `async` and `await`, then you can do it the old-fashioned way for an asynchronous iteration (what we did before `async/await`):

```js
function run(sidArr, callback) {
  let index = 0;
  let results = [];

  function next() {
    // check if we're done and call callback
    if (index >= sidArr.length) {
      // ensure callback is always called asynchronously
      //   even if sidArr is empty
      setImmediate(() => callback(null, results));
      return;
    }
    // still more to process
    client
      .messages(sidArr[index++])
      .update({ body: '' })
      .then((message) => {
        // save result and do next iteration of loop
        results.push(message.sid);
        next();
      })
      .catch(callback);
  }

  next();
}

run(sidArr, putYourCompletionCallbackHere);
```

**Run them sequentially with `async` and `await`:**

For completeness, here's how you would run them sequentially when you can use `async` and `await`:

```js
async function run(sidArr, callback) {
  try {
    let results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < sidArr.length; i++) {
      let data = await client.messages(sidArr[i]).update({ body: '' });
      results.push(data.sid);
    }
    callback(null, results);
  } catch (e) {
    callback(e);
  }
}

run(sidArr, putYourCompletionCallbackHere);
```